# responsive horizontal scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm trying to make a a side-scrolling site effect with two arrows as buttons, using vanilla Javascript and css, with a large horizontal image.

The way I set it up is hiding the body overflow and substracting width with transform translate, while the image is absolutely positioned inside a wrapper (code below for reference). So far it works, but it's not responsive, as the breakpoints aren't setting themselves up in different viewports, and I'd like them to do so.
For example, if the breakpoint is half a tree inside the image, in 1080px wide, I want it to be half a tree in 720, but instead it translates less space and ends up at the left of the tree, thus winding up short at the end of the whole transition.

```
let bg = document.getElementById('page_wrapper')
let ar = document.getElementById('arrow_right')
let al = document.getElementById('arrow_left')
// ar = arrow right, al = arrow left, bg = background(image)
let positions = 
['0%','-65%','-110%','-180%','-247%','-314%','-386%','-486%','-536%']
let pos = 0
function moveRight() {
    pos++;
    if(pos !=0) al.style.display = 'initial';
    if(pos === 8) ar.style.display = 'none';
    bg.style.transform = 'translate('+positions[pos]+')';
}
function moveLeft() {
    pos--;
    if(pos !=8) ar.style.display = 'initial';
    if(pos === 0) al.style.display = 'none';
    bg.style.transform = 'translate('+positions[pos]+')';
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @hungerstar I'm trying to find an horizontal image of such proportions online, but you can always clone my [repo](https://github.com/macravero/mm_challenge.git) (its public and pretty basic atm)

Comment: Use a placeholder service, https://via.placeholder.com/12226x1080